# Push to nested repeated scope in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It is easy to push an item that you just added to a existing repeated section.

The page shows all categories, with their product inside. You can add a new category or product on the page with Angular.

After adding a new one, I want to push it to the correct section. That is easy for the main repeated section, but not for the nested ones.

```
<script>
function ProductsController($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.addCategory = function(category)
    {
        $http.post('/categories', category);
        $scope.categories.push(category);
    }

    $scope.addProduct = function(product)
    {
        $http.post('/products', product);

        // What to do over here? 
        // $scope.categories.push(category);
        // I want this product to be added in the correct category
    }

}
</script>

<article ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <h3>{{ category.title }}</h3>

    <ul ng-repeat="product in category.product">
        <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
    </ul>

    <form ng-submit="addProduct(product)" ng-hide="toggle">
        <!-- The form -->
    </form>
    <p ng-click="toggle = !toggle">New product in this category</p>

</article>

<form ng-submit="addCategory(category)">
    <!-- The form -->
</form>
```

How can I add a newly added product to the category I just added a product to?

Answer (score 1):

You could add the current category when calling the addProduct method

HTML

```
<form ng-submit="addProduct(product, category)" ng-hide="toggle">
    <!-- The form -->
</form>
```

JS

```
$scope.addProduct = function(product, category)
{
    $http.post('/products', product);
    category.product = category.product || [];
    category.product.push(product);
}
```

Comment: I just edited the answer to check if the product array isn't created yet

Answer (score 0):

If your $scope.categories has a nested architecture why not use this syntax to push :

```
$scope.addProduct = function(category, product)
    {
        $http.post('/products', product);
        $scope.categories[category].push(product);
    }
```